# Using Shapely to create polygons from four latitude and longitude corners

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I'm trying to use data files from the ozone monitoring instrument (OMI) and compare data from this source to surface instruments that monitor similar data.

Eventually, I'd like to find whether are within a specific polygon. To do this, though, I need to create the polygons I imagine.

I have the following variables

```
latmat

latmat[1] = array([-62.2546, -62.371 , -62.4871, -62.6032], dtype=float32)
latmat[2] = array([-62.7195, -62.8356, -62.9519, -63.0676], dtype=float32)

lonmat

lonmat[1] = array([135.579, 135.606, 135.633, 135.66 ], dtype=float32)
lonmat[2] = array([135.688, 135.717, 135.745, 135.774], dtype=float32)
```

latmat and lonmat are both much larger than two indices of course, but I'm trying to keep these simple. These values represent the latitude and longitude points of a four-corner satellite pixel respectively.

On top this I also have data in the form

```
data[1] = 1E+15
data[2] = 3E+15
```

How might I go about creating a geodataframe with geopandas that recognizes each combination of 4 lat/lon points as a polygon?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If yes, please mark as accepted answer and upvote. If not, let me know what you need and I'll help you out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up realizing that I could reshape my arrays in to the right polygon with the following code.

```
temp = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.ravel(latcorners)), pd.Series(np.ravel(loncorners))],axis = 1)
temp['id'] = pd.Series(np.repeat([x for x in range(int(len(temp)/4))], 4))
temp['coord'] = list(zip(temp[1], temp[0]))
temp.columns = ['lat','lon','id','coord']
temp_out = temp.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: Polygon(x['coord'].to_list()))
```

This code assigns and "ID" to each variable in my array corresponding to the specific polygon I want the value to be a part of. I then use the final line of code to group by ID and turn each group of coordinates into a polygon.

Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `zip()` for this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon    
import numpy as np

latmat1 = np.array([-62.2546, -62.371 , -62.4871, -62.6032], dtype=np.float32)
latmat2 = np.array([-62.7195, -62.8356, -62.9519, -63.0676], dtype=np.float32)
lonmat1 = np.array([135.579, 135.606, 135.633, 135.66 ], dtype=np.float32)
lonmat2 = np.array([135.688, 135.717, 135.745, 135.774], dtype=np.float32)

pol1 = Polygon([(i,j) for i,j in zip(lonmat1, latmat1 ) ])
pol2 = Polygon([(i,j) for i,j in zip(lonmat2, latmat2 ) ])
```

Comment: Hi Lostman, thanks so much for your help. Sadly, when I try to apply this to latmat (which is size 98580x4 and contains latmat1,latmat2, and many more iterations of the 4-latitude corner output) and lonmat I get the error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me with how I think your data are stored.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon    
import numpy as np

lonmat= [np.array([135.579, 135.606, 135.633, 135.66 ]), np.array([135.688, 135.717, 135.745, 135.774])]
latmat = [np.array([-62.2546, -62.371 , -62.4871, -62.6032]), np.array([-62.7195, -62.8356, -62.9519, -63.0676])]


geom_list = [(x, y) for x, y  in zip(lonmat, latmat)]

geom_list_2 = [Polygon(tuple(zip(x, y))) for x, y in geom_list]
```

[image]